Trying to test an ASP.NET MVC controller with fake it easy but getting an error
Here is my CustomWebApplicationFactory file where I override to try and connect the IUserService.
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    public IUserService _userService;

    public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        _userService = A.Fake<IUserService>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton(_userService);
        });
    }
}

Here is my integration test. The error appears on the A.Callto() below.
A.CallTo(() => _factory._userService.GetAllItems().Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Person>>(fakepersons)));

and the error says:

Error CS1929
'Task<IEnumerable>' does not contain a definition for 'Returns' and the best extension method overload 'ReturnValueConfigurationExtensions.Returns<Task<IEnumerable>>(IReturnValueConfiguration<Task<IEnumerable>>, Task<IEnumerable>)' requires a receiver of type 'FakeItEasy.Configuration.IReturnValueConfiguration<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ReactJS_App.Models.Person>>>'
WebIntegrationTest.Test   C:\Users\srees\ReactJS App\WebIntegrationTest.Test\ControllerTest\HomeControllerIntegrationTests.cs 34  Active

Code:
public class HomeControllerIntegrationTests : IDisposable
{
    private CustomWebApplicationFactory _factory;
    private HttpClient _client;

    public HomeControllerIntegrationTests()
    {
        _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory();
        _client = _factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetAllItems_ReturnOkResult_WithListOFItems()
    {
        var fakepersons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person{Id=1, Firstname="Test1", Lastname="Test1", Email="Test1"},
            new Person { Id = 2, Firstname = "Test2", Lastname = "Test2", Email = "Test2" }
        };

        A.CallTo(() => _factory._userService.GetAllItems().Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Person>>(fakepersons)));

        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/Home");

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _client.Dispose();
        _factory.Dispose();
    }
}

I'm new to testing, so I don't know how to approach this one.

I think you have a closing parenthesis in the wrong place.
The
.Returns(...)
operates on the result of
A.CallTo(() => ...)
so your code should be:
A.CallTo(
    () => _factory._userService.GetAllItems()
) // <- new closing paren here
.Returns(Task.FromResult<...>(fakepersons)); // <- one less paren here

